# Java 2 Security with Axis2 1.4 in Websphere 7

Tags: java, security, websphere, axis, policyfiles

I have a very complex application (let's say enterprise application) deployed in Websphere 7 (with parent last class loader policy) that contains multiple dependencies. The .ear I'm deploying contains 4 .war files inside. One of them is a axis2.war.

Everything works fine until I turn on administrative security and Java 2 security.
After debugging all the AccessControlExceptions and adding the necessary permissions to the **..\profiles\was70profile1\config\cells\AMSCNT0009Node01Cell\applications\app.ear\deployments\app\META-INF\was.policy** and **..\profiles\was70profile1\installedApps\AMSCNT0009Node01Cell\app.ear\META-INF\was.policy** I end up with one AccessControlException that doesn't seem to disappear in any way (java.io.FilePermission C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\profiles\was70profile1\installedApps\AMSCNT0009Node01Cell\app.ear\appAxis2-3.5.2.war\WEB-INF\scriptServices read).

My was.policy files :

```
    /* AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED ON Mon Mar 05 13:40:14 CET 2012*/
/* DO NOT EDIT */

grant codeBase "file:${application}" {
  permission java.util.PropertyPermission "*", "read, write";
  permission java.util.PropertyPermission "org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory", "read, write";
  permission java.util.PropertyPermission "Axis2.prohibitDebugLogging" , "read,write";

  permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "modifyThreadGroup";
  permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "modifyThread";
  permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "createClassLoader";
  permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "setContextClassLoader";
  permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "checkPropertiesAccess";
  permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "getClassLoader";
  permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "loadLibrary.*";
  permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "getProtectionDomain";
  permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "shutdownHooks";
  permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "accessDeclaredMembers";

  permission java.security.SecurityPermission "getPolicy";
  permission javax.management.MBeanServerPermission "createMBeanServer";
  permission java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission "suppressAccessChecks";

  permission com.ibm.oti.shared.SharedClassPermission "java.net.URLClassLoader", "read, write";
  permission com.ibm.oti.shared.SharedClassPermission "org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentClassLoader", "read, write";

  permission java.io.FilePermission "C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\SDP\\runtimes\\base_v7\\profiles\\was70profile1\\attachments", "read, write";
  permission java.io.FilePermission "alerts.log", "read, write";
  permission java.io.FilePermission "jmxPerformance.log", "read, write";
  permission java.io.FilePermission "AppLog.txt", "read, write";
  permission java.io.FilePermission "hibernateStatsLogger.log", "read, write";

  permission java.io.FilePermission "C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\SDP\\runtimes\\base_v7\\plugins\\-", "read";
  permission java.io.FilePermission "C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\SDP\\runtimes\\base_v7\\plugins", "read";
  permission java.io.FilePermission "C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\SDP\\runtimes\\base_v7\\lib\\-", "read";
  permission java.io.FilePermission "C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\SDP\\runtimes\\base_v7\\deploytool\\-", "read";
  permission java.io.FilePermission "C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\SDP\\runtimes\\base_v7\\java\\-", "read";
  permission java.io.FilePermission "C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\SDP\\runtimes\\base_v7\\java\\jre\\lib\\-", "read";
  permission java.io.FilePermission "C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\SDP\\runtimes\\base_v7\\properties\\-", "read, write";
  permission java.io.FilePermission "C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\SDP\\runtimes\\base_v7\\properties\\*", "read, write";

  permission java.io.FilePermission "${app.installed.path}", "read, write";
  permission java.io.FilePermission "${app.installed.path}\\*", "read, write";

  permission java.io.FilePermission "C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\SDP\\runtimes\\base_v7\\profiles\\was70profile1\\logs\\_axis2", "read, write, delete";
  permission java.io.FilePermission "C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\SDP\\runtimes\\base_v7\\profiles\\was70profile1\\logs\\_axis2\\*", "read, write, delete";
  permission java.io.FilePermission "C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\SDP\\runtimes\\base_v7\\profiles\\was70profile1\\logs\\_axis2\\-", "read, write, delete";

  permission java.io.FilePermission "C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\SDP\\runtimes\\base_v7\\profiles\\was70profile1\\temp\\AMSCNT0009Node01\\server1\\app", "read, write, delete";
  permission java.io.FilePermission "C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\SDP\\runtimes\\base_v7\\profiles\\was70profile1\\temp\\AMSCNT0009Node01\\server1\\app\\*", "read, write, delete";
  permission java.io.FilePermission "C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\SDP\\runtimes\\base_v7\\profiles\\was70profile1\\temp\\AMSCNT0009Node01\\server1\\app\\-", "read, write, delete";
  permission java.io.FilePermission "${app.installed.path}\\appAxis2-3.5.2.war\\WEB-INF\\classes\\-", "read";
  permission java.io.FilePermission "${app.installed.path}\\appAxis2-3.5.2.war\\WEB-INF\\conf\\-", "read";
  permission java.io.FilePermission "${app.installed.path}\\appAxis2-3.5.2.war\\java\\-", "read";
  permission java.io.FilePermission "${app.installed.path}\\appAxis2-3.5.2.war\\java\\*", "read";
  permission java.io.FilePermission "${app.installed.path}\\appAxis2-3.5.2.war\\java\\conf\\-", "read";
  permission java.io.FilePermission "${app.installed.path}\\appAxis2-3.5.2.war\\WEB-INF", "read";
  permission java.io.FilePermission "${app.installed.path}\\appAxis2-3.5.2.war\\WEB-INF\\-", "read";
  permission java.io.FilePermission "${app.installed.path}\\appAxis2-3.5.2.war\\WEB-INF\\scriptServices", "read, write";
  permission java.io.FilePermission "${app.installed.path}\\appAxis2-3.5.2.war\\WEB-INF\\scriptServices\\*", "read, write";
  permission java.io.FilePermission "${app.installed.path}\\appAxis2-3.5.2.war\\WEB-INF\\modules\\*", "read, write";
  permission java.io.FilePermission "${app.installed.path}\\appAxis2-3.5.2.war\\WEB-INF\\services\\*", "read, write";

  permission java.io.FilePermission "${app.installed.path}\\appModelSvcs-1.4.2.war\\WEB-INF\\scriptServices", "read, write";  
  permission java.io.FilePermission "${app.installed.path}\\appModelSvcs-1.4.2.war\\WEB-INF\\scriptServices\\*", "read, write";
  permission java.io.FilePermission "${app.installed.path}\\appModelSvcs-1.4.2.war\\WEB-INF\\modules\\-", "read, write";
  permission java.io.FilePermission "${app.installed.path}\\appModelSvcs-1.4.2.war\\WEB-INF\\services\\-", "read, write";
  permission java.io.FilePermission "${app.installed.path}\\appModelSvcs-1.4.2.war\\WEB-INF\\-", "read";
  permission java.io.FilePermission "${app.installed.path}\\appModelSvcs-1.4.2.war\\WEB-INF", "read";

  permission java.io.FilePermission "${app.installed.path}\\appEFDSimulator-3.5.2.war\\WEB-INF\\*", "read, write";

  permission java.io.FilePermission "C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\SDP\\runtimes\\base_v7\\profiles\\was70profile1", "read, write";
  permission java.io.FilePermission "C:\\Program Files\\IBM\\SDP\\runtimes\\base_v7\\profiles\\was70profile1\\properties", "read, write";
};
```

The trace :

```
    [3/8/12 16:41:24:320 CET] 00000018 SecurityManag W   SECJ0314W: Current Java 2 Security policy reported a potential violation of Java 2 Security Permission. Refer to the InfoCenter for further information.

Permission:

      C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\profiles\was70profile1\installedApps\AMSCNT0009Node01Cell\app.ear\appAxis2-3.5.2.war\WEB-INF\scriptServices : Access denied (java.io.FilePermission C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\profiles\was70profile1\installedApps\AMSCNT0009Node01Cell\app.ear\appAxis2-3.5.2.war\WEB-INF\scriptServices read)

Code:

     org.apache.axis2.scripting.ScriptRepositoryListener$1  in  {file:/C:/Program Files/IBM/SDP/runtimes/base_v7/profiles/was70profile1/temp/AMSCNT0009Node01/server1/app/appAxis2-3.5.2.war/_axis2/axis23638axis2-scripting-1.4.mar}


Stack Trace:

java.security.AccessControlException: Access denied (java.io.FilePermission C:\Program Files\IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\profiles\was70profile1\installedApps\AMSCNT0009Node01Cell\app.ear\appAxis2-3.5.2.war\WEB-INF\scriptServices read)
    at java.lang.Throwable.<init>(Throwable.java:67)
    at java.security.AccessControlException.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:108)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:532)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:210)
    at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkRead(SecurityManager.java:871)
    at java.io.File.list(File.java:982)
    at java.io.File.listFiles(File.java:1062)
    at org.apache.axis2.scripting.ScriptRepositoryListener$1.run(ScriptRepositoryListener.java:47)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:202)
    at org.apache.axis2.java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:78)
    at org.apache.axis2.scripting.ScriptRepositoryListener.findServicesInDirectory(ScriptRepositoryListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:225)
    at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadServices(DeploymentEngine.java:131)
```

I've already tried changing axis2 1.4 source code too, replacing axis2-kernel.jar and axis2-scripting-1.4.mar with custom ones with the fix below :

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS2-3816

I've also tried changing the axis2 source code, by selecting a different folder than WEB-INF\scriptServices, but the AccessControlException remains, now in the new folder.

If anyone has an hint on how to fix this, it would be very appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that the only solution is removing the scripting-xxx.mar from the modules folder.
Axis2 1.5 comes with the doPrivileged() method in the ScriptRepositoryListener class, but it doesn't work as well.